# Creating a function to remove only specific word in a list (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, tidyverse, sentiment-analysis

I have a list with undesirable words (in spanish) which are meaningless, but they are also present inside another. I just want to remove it when they are a term, not when they are a piece of another word.

For example: "la" is an spanish article, but if I use a function to remove it, also will break into two words a useful term like "relacion" (which means relationship)

My first choice was creating a function to remove this terms.

```
bdtidy$tweet <- #here are tweets
fix.useless <- function(doc) {   
function(doc) {
doc <- gsub("la", ".", doc)
doc <- gsub("las", ".", doc)
doc <- gsub("el", ".", doc)
doc <- gsub("ellos", ".", doc)
doc <- gsub("ellas", ".", doc)
return(doc)
 }

bdtidy$tweet <- sapply(bdtidy$tweet, fix.useless)
```

My second choice was with a list, and then using filter inside the df

```
nousar <- c("rt", "pero", "para"...)
new df %>% bdtidy %>%
 filter(!tweet $in$ nousar))
```

But always the result is removing all those words and breaking terms in two words which makes my analysis useless.
Thanks.

Comment: If you first `gsub("el", ".", doc)` then `"ellos"` becomes `".los"` and the following `gsub("ellos", ".", doc)` does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove single words from a string is by flanking the words with spaces, such as this example:

```
# sample input
x <- c("Get rid of la but not lala")
# pattern with spaces flanking target word
y <- gsub(" la ", " ", x)
# output
> y
[1] "Get rid of but not lala"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tokenize the words. That is, extract the individual words. Once they are extracted you can check the tokens for matches and remove them. The `stringr` package can help you here

```
#sample text
text <- "hola, me llamo struggles. El package 'stringr' puede resolver la pregunta."

#normalize text by making everything lowercase
lower_text <- stringr::str_to_lower(text)

#split text at anything that isn't a number or a letter
tokens <- stringr::str_split(lower_text, "[^[:alnum:]]+")

#create a list of stop words
stop_words <- c('la', 'las', 'el', 'ellos')

#remove words that are in the stop words vector
tokens[[1]][!tokens[[1]] %in% stop_words]
```

Since you'll probably be doing this with a lot of tweets, I suggest you also take a look at the `tidytext` package and read through the tutorial https://www.tidytextmining.com/

```
df <- data.frame(
  tweet = text,
  tweet_id = 1234,
  user = 'struggles',
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

twitter_tokens <- tidytext::unnest_tokens(df, word, tweet)

clean_twitter_tokens <- dplyr::filter(twitter_tokens, !word %in% stop_words)
```

and this will give you something like

```
  tweet_id      user      word
1     1234 struggles      hola
2     1234 struggles        me
3     1234 struggles     llamo
4     1234 struggles struggles
5     1234 struggles   package
6     1234 struggles   stringr
7     1234 struggles     puede
8     1234 struggles  resolver
9     1234 struggles  pregunta
```

And if you want to keep it together in one sentence then the following will bring it back:

```
lean_twitter_tokens %>%
  dplyr::group_by(tweet_id, user) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(tweet = stringr::str_c(word, collapse = ' '))
```

giving you

```
  tweet_id user      tweet                                                          
     <dbl> <chr>     <chr>                                                          
1     1234 struggles hola me llamo struggles package stringr puede resolver pregunta
```